# Castling on King side

Tags: puzzles, castling

[image: Castling on King side]

This is a quiz from a chess website. The challenge is to castle on King Side. White to play. How can we do this ?

Comment: You cant!If you want to castle at the king side you first need to play 1.Bg2 , then hope Black is drunk and he/she moves his/her knight from h3.

Comment: Easy. Black is already castled kingside.  Done.

Comment: Can you give a link to the "quiz from a chess website"? That may help shed light on what is meant to be going on here!

Comment: The position is illegal, with two light-squared bishops and no missing pawn for Black. So, since chess rules are not respected anyway, you can go 1.0-0.

Answer (score 6):

- bypassing the position's illegality
- assuming that White's goal is to castle kingside and that Black aims to prevent it,

then :

> 1.Bg2 is mandatory: we won't ever castle kingside if the Rh1 moves or is captured, so 1.Bg2 or 1.Ng2 is necessary to prevent 1...Bxh1. However, after 1.Ng2? Nxf2! we can prevent 2...Nxh1 only by moving Rh1 or Ke1, losing castling rights.

But after

> 1.Bg2 Bxg2 2.Nxg2 Nc6
>  White still needs many moves to get rid of the Nh3 that controls g1. Meanwhile, Black threatens ...Nd4 forking the checking squares c2 and f3 for which they would force the Ke1 to move.
>  3.c3 Ne5 (aiming at d3 or f3) is insufficient, so White must play
>  3.Na3 Nd4 4.Nh4 to parry the threats.

Alas,

> 4...Ng1 is then decisive, when 5...Ndf3 cannot be parried: either the Rh1 or the Ke1 will have to move without castling.

As a conclusion :

> White won't be able to castle kingside if Black tries to prevent it.